# Why is my method undefined for the type object?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm not sure why Eclipse is giving me this error:

> The method `listen()` is undefined for the type `Object`

What simple mistake am I making? Also, is my code the right way to write a `main` method which instantiates an `EchoServer0` object and calls its `listen` method?

```
public class EchoServer0 {    
    public void listen() {
        ServerSocket socket = null;
        try{
            socket = new ServerSocket(2013);
            System.out.println("Opened server socket");
            socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
            socket.accept();
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException ste){
            System.out.println("Timed out after " + 2000 + " ms");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getClass().getName()+" at server: " + e.getMessage());
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object EchoServer0;
        EchoServer0.listen();
    } 
}
```

Comment: `The method listen() is undefined for the type Object` It's pretty straight forward. The Object class does not contain that method. Declare your `EchoServer0` variable as a type with that method.

Comment: The compiler uses the declared type of a variable to see what methods it supports.  If you write `Object name="Stack Overflow"`, then you can call on `name` only the methods of `Object`.  The compiler has no choice.  Between the declaration and a method call, somebody could write `name = Integer.valueOf(1)`. The actual method that gets called depends on the value of `name`, and the declared types of the method arguments.

Answer (score 13):

Change your main to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EchoServer echoServer = new EchoServer();
    echoServer.listen();
}
```

When you declare `Object EchoServer0;` you have a few mistakes.

1. EchoServer0 is of type Object, therefore it doesn't have the method listen().
2. You will also need to create an instance of it with `new`.
3. Another problem, this is only regarding naming conventions, you should call your variables  starting by lower case letters, echoServer0 instead of EchoServer0. Uppercase names are usually for class names.
4. You should not create a variable with the same name as its class. It is confusing.

Comment: You might want to give a snippet of info about why this works compared to what the OP had instead of just the code. +1 for correct solution though.

Comment: Thanks. I will add a few comments.

Comment: This isn't "only" a naming convention problem, because the variable name has the same name as his class name, which can only cause confusion.

Comment: I had to try to see if that compiles.

Comment: EchoServer EchoServer = new EchoServer();
EchoServer.echo();  // and echo() is not static!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EchoServer0 myServer;
    myServer = new EchoServer0();
    myServer.listen();
}
```

What you were trying to do was declaring a variable of type `Object`, not creating anything for that variable to reference, then trying to call a method that didn't exist (in the class `Object`) on an object that hadn't been  created.  It was never going to work.

Comment: This is just pure curiosity: Why don't you declare and initialize on the same line? Just preference?

Comment: Yeah.  He/she might want to do other stuff in between, I guess.  But this is really just a habit more than anything.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Object EchoServer0;
```

says that you are allocating an `Object` named `EchoServer0`. This has nothing to do with the class `EchoServer0`. Furthermore, the object is not initialized, so `EchoServer0` is `null`. Classes and identifiers have separate namespaces.  This will actually compile:

```
String String = "abc";  // My use of String String was deliberate.
```

Please keep to the Java naming standards: classes begin with a capital letter, identifiers begin with a small letter, constants and `enum`s are all-capitals.

```
public final String ME = "Eric Jablow";
public final double GAMMA = 0.5772;
public enum Color { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, INDIGO, VIOLET}
public COLOR background = Color.RED;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EchoServer0 e = new EchoServer0();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        e.listen();
}
```

Your variable of type `Object` truly doesn't have such a method, but the type `EchoServer0` you define above certainly has.