# iReport is throwing me these same 3 exceptions (SQL)

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm in iReport and I'm simply trying to open an existing report but whenever I attempt to compile it I get these same 3 errors with my code/arguments.

---

> The method getCompanyReportAddress(Integer) is undefined for the type CompanyModule
>                   value = ((com.evnt.eve.modules.CompanyModule) ((com.evnt.eve.modules.EVEModule) ((java.lang.Object)parameter_module.getValue())).getInstance(com.evnt.eve.modules.CompanyModule.class)).getCompanyReportAddress(((java.lang.Integer)field_LOCATIONGROUPID.getValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=37$
>
> ### >

My XML Code (My Main report not subreports)

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports     http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PackingList" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="552" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a87f62d2-3104-4786-a934-8096b4c706a1">
<property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
<import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
<import value="java.util.*"/>
<import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
<style name="9" fontName="Arial" fontSize="9" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="10" isDefault="true" fontName="Arial" fontSize="10" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="12" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="14" fontName="Arial" fontSize="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="10b" fontName="Arial" fontSize="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="12b" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="14b" fontName="Arial" fontSize="14" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="16b" fontName="Arial" fontSize="16" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="18b" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="24b" fontName="Arial" fontSize="24" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="10i" fontName="Arial" fontSize="10" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="12i" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="10bu" fontName="Arial" fontSize="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="true" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="header1" fontName="Arial" fontSize="24" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="header2" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="header3" fontName="Arial" fontSize="16" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="addressHeader" fontName="Arial" fontSize="14" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="date" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="type" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="address" fontName="Arial" fontSize="10" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="column_head" fontName="Arial" fontSize="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="body" isDefault="true" fontName="Arial" fontSize="10" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<style name="note" isDefault="true" fontName="Arial" fontSize="9" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
<parameter name="shipID" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["7"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="path" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["../Ship/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="module" class="java.lang.Object" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="REPORTDESCRIPTION" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Packing List for a selected order. Selecting Standard or By Location layouts will include backorder items."]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="ckShowKitHeaders" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[80,90]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["80"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="ckShowCountry" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[1,0]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="cbOrderNumber" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[SO,SO Number,PO,Customer PO Number]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["PO"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="cbLayoutFormat" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[standard,Standard,carton,By Carton,location,By Location]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["standard"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="cbContactToShow" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[address,Address Name,contact,SO Contact]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["address"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="ShowUniqueShipNumbers" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[false]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="ShowBarcode" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[true]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="ShowTracking" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[true]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="ckShowBackOrderItems" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[100,101]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["100"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT ship.id AS ShipID,
CASE WHEN ship.ORDERTYPEID = 20 THEN ship.SOID
 WHEN ship.ORDERTYPEID = 10 THEN ship.POID
 WHEN ship.ORDERTYPEID = 40 THEN ship.XOID
 ELSE 0 END AS OrderID, ship.ORDERTYPEID AS OrderType
FROM ship
WHERE ship.id = $P{shipID}]]>
</queryString>
<field name="SHIPID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="ORDERID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="ORDERTYPE" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<group name="SOPackingList">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(1)]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{ORDERTYPE}.intValue() == 20)]]></printWhenExpression>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement key="subreport-5" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="552" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="fba8ca5d-4b1b-4c9a-a7be-5203ad229af0">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{ORDERTYPE}.intValue() == 20)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="cbOrderNumber">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{cbOrderNumber}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="shipID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPID}.toString()]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="module">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{module}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ShowTracking">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowTracking}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="cbContactToShow">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{cbContactToShow}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ckShowCountry">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ckShowCountry}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="path">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{path}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ckShowBackOrderItems">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ckShowBackOrderItems}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ShowUniqueShipNumbers">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowUniqueShipNumbers}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ShowBarcode">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowBarcode}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ckShowKitHeaders">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ckShowKitHeaders}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{cbLayoutFormat}.equals("standard") ?
$P{path} + "SOPackingListTacticalMedical2015.jasper" :
$P{cbLayoutFormat}.equals("carton") ?
    $P{path} + "cartonSOPackingList.jasper" :
    $P{path} + "SOPackingListLoc.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="POPackingList">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[null]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{ORDERTYPE}.intValue() == 10)]]></printWhenExpression>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement key="subreport-5" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="552" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="1ca9c614-da10-4586-8eef-89be976185c9">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{ORDERTYPE}.intValue() == 10)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="module">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{module}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="shipID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPID}.toString()]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ShowTracking">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowTracking}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ckShowCountry">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ckShowCountry}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="path">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{path}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ShowUniqueShipNumbers">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowUniqueShipNumbers}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ShowBarcode">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowBarcode}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{cbLayoutFormat}.equals("standard") ?
$P{path} + "POPackingList.jasper" :
$P{cbLayoutFormat}.equals("carton") ?
    $P{path} + "cartonPOPackingList.jasper" :
    $P{path} + "POPackingListLoc.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="TOPackingList">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[null]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement key="subreport-6" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="552" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="3e7ba540-32a9-43fd-bfe0-fa5d0a47163c">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{ORDERTYPE}.intValue() == 40)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="module">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{module}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="shipID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPID}.toString()]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ShowTracking">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowTracking}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ckShowCountry">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ckShowCountry}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="path">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{path}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ShowUniqueShipNumbers">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowUniqueShipNumbers}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ShowBarcode">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ShowBarcode}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{cbLayoutFormat}.equals("standard") ?
$P{path} + "TOPackingList.jasper" :
$P{cbLayoutFormat}.equals("carton") ?
    $P{path} + "cartonTOPackingList.jasper" :
    $P{path} + "TOPackingListLoc.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch">
        <image scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Bottom" isUsingCache="true">
            <reportElement key="image" mode="Opaque" x="-36" y="-352" width="423" height="40" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="eb00e2de-9362-4b7c-8cef-4d0b7852f9ff">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{module} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            </box>
            <graphicElement fill="Solid">
                <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
            </graphicElement>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[com.evnt.util.ImageUtil.decodeImage(((com.evnt.eve.modules.ImageModule) ((com.evnt.eve.modules.EVEModule) $P{module}).getInstance(com.evnt.eve.modules.ImageModule.class)).getImageData("Company", 1, true))]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <image scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Bottom" isUsingCache="true">
            <reportElement key="image" mode="Opaque" x="-36" y="-352" width="423" height="40" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2a295a79-a48d-40fb-8a72-db8fb557157b">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{module} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            </box>
            <graphicElement fill="Solid">
                <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
            </graphicElement>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[com.evnt.util.ImageUtil.decodeImage(((com.evnt.eve.modules.ImageModule) ((com.evnt.eve.modules.EVEModule) $P{module}).getInstance(com.evnt.eve.modules.ImageModule.class)).getImageData("Company", 1, true))]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-1" mode="Transparent" x="323" y="0" width="183" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="57d6609c-9663-4e85-aa06-bfaed4a5feaa"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Bottom" rotation="None">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="9"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " of "]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-2" mode="Transparent" x="506" y="0" width="46" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="dd0b3ac2-433f-4a1f-9cb6-f6686657a095"/>
            <box leftPadding="3">
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom" rotation="None">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="9"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["" + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-3" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="323" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0d7479d6-f007-42a0-b68e-f621b692bbd3"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom" rotation="None">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="9"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><!   [CDATA[(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,DateFormat.LONG)).format(new Date())]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Thank you guys for any help!

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I feel I asked my question to the best of my ability. I explained my problem and gave the errors that I'm having.

Comment: Unless you show how the report is made or how you call it, we cant do much beside guess.

Comment: Okay- that comment seems better then your first. I'll post the report! Thanks!

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza should i post my XML?

Comment: Again if you read  the link you will understand what i mean How to ask. You have to provide enought information so we can replicate the issue. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @colt In this report, you are using 3 subreports. and the error your getting is not from the code you have pasted here., add appropriate code in which your getting error. From the error you have mentioned.. it is clear that the method is undefined. for that you can also look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246489/why-is-my-method-undefined-for-the-type-object

Comment: @ManiDeep I can post the 3 sub report code if you need that. Thanks for answering me. I am still having this issue!

Comment: @colt I feel that, there is no problem with the report, here in report you are using some methods from another class files(jars) which are not included in ireport. check that.

Comment: @ManiDeep thank you for your help and I have suspected that the issue is my lack of the correct .jar files- the issue is i can't figure out which ones i need and where to get them. :/